# python: functions from math and os modules are interrupted by EINTR

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, arm, eintr

I have linux board on samsung SoC s3c6410 (ARM11). 
I build rootfs with buildroot:
Python 2.7.1, uClibc-0.9.31. 
Linux kernel:
Linux buildroot 2.6.28.6 #177 Mon Oct 3 12:50:57 EEST 2011 armv6l GNU/Linux

My app, written on python, in some mysterios conditons raise this exceptions:

1)
exception:

```
 File "./dfbUtils.py", line 3209, in setItemData
ValueError: (4, 'Interrupted system call')
```

code:

```
currentPage=int(math.floor(float(rowId)/self.pageSize))==self.selectedPage
```

2)
exception:

```
File "./terminalGlobals.py", line 943, in getFirmawareName
OSError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call: 'firmware'
```

code:

```
for fileName in os.listdir('firmware'):
```

Some info about app: it have 3-7 threads, listen serial ports via 'serial' module, use gui implemented via c extension that wrap directfb, i can't reproduce this exceptions, they are not predictable.

I googled for EINTR exceptions in python, but only found that EINTR can occur only on slow system calls and python's modules socket, subprocess and another one is already process EINTR. So what happens in my app? Why simple call of math function can interrupt program at any time, it's not reliable at all. I have only suggestions: ulibc bug, kernel/hw handling bug. But this suggestions don't show me solution.

Now i created wrap functions (that restart opertion in case of EINTR) around some functions from os module, but wrapping math module will increase execution time in 2 times. There another question: if math can be interrutped than other module also can and how to get reliability?

P.S. I realize that library call (to libm for example) is not system call, so why i have "Interrupted system call"?

Comment: Are you sure that the exception occurs in `math.floor`? I don't know in which type of object you are putting your code, but in principle `self.pageSize` or `self.selectedPage` could trigger other function calls.

Comment: All vars is python ints, no other call was done. I have never seen combination of ValueError and errno==4. if python really does some slow system call from 
module os, why it doesn't handle EINTR and not restart call. Is 
SA_RESTART flag in signal can be solution? But how i can set this 
flag? By placing flag for signal handler in c extension (or ctypes 
manipulation)?

Comment: Complete shot in the dark, but when you built uclibc, which threading model did you select?  I've had strange issues with python and uclibu in the past that were fixed by recompling uclibc with different threading support.

Answer (score 0):

There was an old bug with threads and `EINTR` in uClibc (#4994) that they fixed in 0.9.30. The fix was tested against pthreads, so I would second the suggestion by tMC to check how you configured threads when building uClibc.

Also you could try compiling with the malloc-simple option? It is slow, but if your issue disappears it may suggest threading issues as well:

> `malloc-simple` is trivially simple and slow as molasses.  It
>         was written from scratch for uClibc, and is the simplest possible
>         (and therefore smallest) malloc implementation.
>
> This uses only the `mmap()` system call to allocate and free memory,
>         and does not use the `brk()` system call at all, making it a fine
>         choice for MMU-less systems with very limited memory.  It's 100%
>         standards compliant, **thread safe**, very small, and releases freed
>         memory back to the OS immediately rather than keeping it in the
>         process's heap for reallocation.  It is also VERY SLOW.